# How to combine/nest qmake spec variables?

Tags: qt, variables, qmake

I'd like to create a variable in QMAKESPEC file, based on the other variables, like below (see also comments inline):

```
# some project-related paths
PROJECT_ABC_ROOT_PATH=$HOME/dev/project_one
PROJECT_XYZ_ROOT_PATH=$HOME/dev/project_two

# variable below is used to select one from the paths above
PROJ_NAME=ABC
# [1] this gives "projec_one" path properly
CURRENT_PATH=$${PROJECT_ABC_ROOT_PATH}
# [2] this doesn't work
CURRENT_PATH=$${PROJECT_$${PROJ_NAME}_ROOT_PATH}
```

Can anyone give advice on how could I correct version [2] please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following :

```
# some project-related paths
PROJECT_ABC_ROOT_PATH=$HOME/dev/project_one
PROJECT_XYZ_ROOT_PATH=$HOME/dev/project_two

# variable below is used to select one from the paths above
PROJ_NAME=ABC
CURRENT_PATH=$$eval(PROJECT_$${PROJ_NAME}_ROOT_PATH)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I wanted to achieve.